# Mysterious IndexError

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I've been getting errors similar to this recently:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-59ca523b1b36> in <module>()
----> 1 first_experiment_comb(model)

  c:\python26\26664\lib\site-packages\experiments.py in first_experiment_comb(mod
 l)
     172                      "Number NZ: " + str(modelz[j].NumNZs) +"\n")
     173
 --> 174         first_experiment(modelz[j], str(j))
     175
     176

c:\python26\26664\lib\site-packages\experiments.py in first_experiment(model, e
t)
     89         plt.close()
     90
---> 91     fl.timberFlow(model)
     92     plt.savefig(dire + "\\timber_flow" +ext+".pdf", bbox_inches = 0)
     93     plt.close()

C:\Python26\26664\lib\site-packages\func_lib.py in timberFlow(model)
    304     if not unVars:
    305         unVars = varValues(model, 'PIEHTLVOL')
--> 306
    307     for i in range(19):
    308             swVarVals.append(swVars[i].X)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Where the final line of the trace points to code that doesn't exist, or in previous cases has been commented out. When I run the last function (in func_lib.py) on it's own I never get the mysterious IndexError, only when it's called from experiments.py.

I'm running this in pylab python 2.6 W64.
I haven't been able to find known bug in iPython or Pylab docs about this.

How could line 306 be the root of the error?

Comment: Your code is out of sync with the bytecode. Reload your code properly.

Comment: I see this whenever I edit the file in the package but do not recompile. Perhaps there is a more proper way to reload the code, but what I do is, delete `func_lib.pyc`, and then restart python and re-import the module this is from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is out of sync with the bytecode. Reload your code properly.

When an exception occurs, the bytecode is inspected for a filename and a linenumber, and then the sourcefile is loaded to show the original source for that line.

If, however, you changed the source but did not yet restart your python process (or reloaded the code in ipython) then the wrong lines are being shown when an exception occurs.

Comment: I've been using %ed then saving the code and re-running. Does this not reload the code properly?

Comment: Not always; there are caveats. See the [ipython autoreload documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) which lists some.

Comment: Rule of thumb: when your tracebacks no longer make sense, you need to restart ipython. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Great rule of thumb; I'll remember that.